# Getting error while loading file in pig:

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am trying to execute pig script in terminal and i am getting following error:

```
INFO  [Thread-13] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader     - Loaded the native-hadoop library
WARN  [Thread-13]    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient     - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
INFO  [Thread-13]    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient     - Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-biadmin/mapred/staging/biadmin-341199244/.staging/job_local_0001
ERROR [Thread-13] org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation     - PriviledgedActionException as:biadmin cause:org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: file:/home/biadmin/PIGData/books.csv
ERROR [main] org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats     - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backend error: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: file:/home/biadmin/PIGData/books.csv
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1041)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:959)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:912)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:573)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:912)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:886)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.Job.submit(Job.java:378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.startReadyJobs(JobControl.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:279)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:260)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/biadmin/PIGData/books.csv
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:235)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:252)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:273)
        ... 15 more

ERROR [main] org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil     - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
ERROR [main]      org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt     - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias b
Details at logfile: /opt/ibm/biginsights/pig/bin/pig_1487413261020.log
```

can anybody help me to resolve this?

The code:

```
data = LOAD '/home/biadmin/PIGData/books.csv';
b = FOREACH data GENERATE $0;
DUMP b;
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: data = LOAD '/home/biadmin/PIGData/books.csv'; 
b = FOREACH data GENERATE $0; 
DUMP b;

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above exception , the input file is not there in the given path file:/home/biadmin/PIGData/books.csv. (which is local file system path)

Pig has two execution modes:
1. local mode (To process local file system files)
$ pig -x local
2. Mapreduce mode (To process HDFS file system files)
$ pig  or  $ pig -x mapreduce

Make sure that you are running the pig script in appropriate mode.